# How to use valgrind with python?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to memcheck a C python extension I am writing, but I'm having trouble setting up valgrind to work with python. I would really appreciate some advice. Just for context, this is Ubuntu 13.10, python 2.7.5+, and valgrind 3.8.1.

As per recommendation from [`Readme.valgrind`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/README.valgrind) I did the following.

1) Downloaded the python source with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python2.7
apt-get source python2.7
```

2) Applied the code patch, i.e. "Uncomment Py_USING_MEMORY_DEBUGGER in Objects/obmalloc.c".

3) Applied the suppression patch, i.e. "Uncomment the lines in Misc/valgrind-python.supp that suppress the warnings for PyObject_Free and PyObject_Realloc"

4) Compiled python with

```
./configure --prefix=/home/dejan/workspace/python --without-pymalloc
make -j4 install
```

Note that I did both 2 and 3, while README.valgrind says to do 2 or 3... more can't hurt.

Now, let's test this on some sample python code in `test.py`

```
print "Test"
```

Let's run valgrind on python with this script

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --suppressions=python2.7-2.7.5/Misc/valgrind-python.supp bin/python test.py
```

Unexpectedly, there is still loads of reports from valgrind, with the first one being (and many more following)

```
==27944== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27944==     in use at exit: 857,932 bytes in 5,144 blocks  
==27944==   total heap usage: 22,766 allocs, 17,622 frees, 4,276,934 bytes allocated
==27944== 
==27944== 38 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 24 of 1,343
==27944==    at 0x4C2A2DB: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27944==    by 0x46B8DD: PyString_FromString (stringobject.c:143)
==27944==    by 0x439631: PyFile_FromFile (fileobject.c:157)
==27944==    by 0x4E9B4A: _PySys_Init (sysmodule.c:1383)
==27944==    by 0x4E29E9: Py_InitializeEx (pythonrun.c:222)
==27944==    by 0x4154B4: Py_Main (main.c:546)
==27944==    by 0x577DDE4: (below main) (libc-start.c:260)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to valgrind a python script that doesn't leak and get clean valgrind output?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519276/is-it-normal-that-running-python-under-valgrind-shows-many-errors-with-memory?rq=1

Comment: @VooDooNOFX I've searched stackoverflow and beyond and all answers basically say that I should do what I described I did -- compile python or use a supress. This does get rid of the custom allocation problematic reports such as PyObject_Free (this is the one in the question you linked), but the reports I'm getting are not of that sort.

Comment: In order to test my c extension, I compiled debug python with instructions provided in the Answer. And I rebuild my extension with debug version python, and it got failure result.
I used setuptools extension build the extension, and it works well under system environment.
The build flags are very different.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://code.google.com/p/distnumpy/wiki/valgrind).

Python also needs to be compiled in debug mode, i.e.

```
./configure --prefix=/home/dejan/workspace/python --without-pymalloc --with-pydebug --with-valgrind
```

In addition, numpy has a [suppresion file](http://code.google.com/p/distnumpy/source/browse/trunk/misc/valgrind.supp?r=257) that gets rid of the extra valgrind warnings.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research for everyone! Do you know if one should recompile python once done using valgrind? And, more importantly - how to do it?

Comment: What works for me is compiling/installing a valgrind-compatible version of python, then basing a virtualenv on that. That gives me the convenient `activate` script. Even better with `virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: does this make every python command call run with valgrind? I'm noticing a significant slow down installing packages with pip

Comment: @JamesRobertAlbert From the README: Note: configuring python --without-pymalloc makes Python run much slower, especially when running under Valgrind. ... It seems to take
about 5 times longer to run --without-pymalloc

Comment: @YairDaon you don't have to recompile Python because you create a new interpreter. Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697863/questions-about-compiling-python-in-debug-mode.

Comment: @DRz Thanks!! I have to be honest - I don't remember why I needed it but thank you so much for the response!!!

Answer (score 68):

Since python 3.6, there's a `PYTHONMALLOC` environment variable which is available in release builds, without needing to recompile.

```
PYTHONMALLOC=malloc python3 foobar.py
```

This will disable pymalloc and just use the libc malloc directly, making it valgrind-friendly. This is equivalent to `--without-pymalloc` (and it is just as slow)

If valgrind is too slow, other values can be helpful. `PYTHONMALLOC=debug` and `PYTHONMALLOC=malloc_debug` add debug hooks on top of the default and the libc allocators respectively. Their effects, from the docs:

> - Newly allocated memory is filled with the byte 0xCB
> - Freed memory is filled with the byte 0xDB
> - Detect violations of the Python memory allocator API. For example, PyObject_Free() called on a memory block allocated by PyMem_Malloc().
> - Detect writes before the start of a buffer (buffer underflows)
> - Detect writes after the end of a buffer (buffer overflows)
> - Check that the GIL is held when allocator functions of PYMEM_DOMAIN_OBJ (ex: PyObject_Malloc()) and PYMEM_DOMAIN_MEM (ex: PyMem_Malloc()) domains are called.

This will catch some uninitialized reads, some use after free, some buffer under/overflows, etc, but won't report leaks and won't touch memory that isn't allocated through python (When using glibc, the `MALLOC_PERTURB_` and `MALLOC_CHECK_` environment variables might help there)

See also:

- [Details of the available values](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONMALLOC)
- [3.6 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pythonmalloc) with usage notes
- [Current location of README.valgrind](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Misc/README.valgrind)