# How to profile python process for memory usage?

Tags: python, linux, django, debugging, gdb

We own a corporate level forum which is developed using python (with Django framework). We are **intermittently** observing **memory usage spikes** on our production setup and we wish to track the cause.

The occurrences of these incidences are **random** and not directly related to the load (as per current study).

I have browsed a lot on internet and especially **stackoverflow** for some suggestions and was not able to get any similar situation.

Yes, I was able to locate a lot of profiler utils like [Python memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler) but these require some code level inclusion of these modules and as this happens to be in production profiler are not a great help (we plan to review our implementation in the next release).

We wish to review this issue based on occurrence.

Thus I wish to check whether there is any tool that we can use to create a dump for analysis offline (just like heapdumps in java).

Any pointers? 
Is gdb the only option?

OS: Linux
Python: 2.7 (currently we do not plan to upgrade until that can help in fixing this issue)

Cheers!

AJ

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try using valgrind. It's a bit tricky, but you can follow up here if you are interested in it

[How to use valgrind with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112989/how-to-use-valgrind-with-python)