# Python: Ctypes how to check memory management

Tags: python, c, memory-management, valgrind, ctypes

So I'm using Python as a front end GUI that interacts with some C files for storage and memory management as a backend. Whenever the GUI's window is closed or exited, I call all the destructor methods for my allocated variables.

Is there anyway to check memory leaks or availability, like a C Valgrind check, right before exiting the whole program to make sure there wasn't any memory leaks?

Example exit:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()  # New GUI
# some code here

def destructorMethods:
    myFunctions.destructorLinkedList()  # Destructor method of my allocated memory in my C file
    # Here is where I would want to run a Valgrind/Memory management check before closing
    root.destroy()  # close the program

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destructorMethods)  # When the close window option is pressed call destructorMethods function
```

Comment: Did you write the C code? Because the easiest option here by far is to just fix your memory leaks. 

Does the python code have knowledge of all C allocations? If so, you could create a basic garbage collector in python to track your blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Valgrind`, then this [readme](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/README.valgrind) might be helpful. Probably, [this](https://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging/valgrind.html) could be another good resource to make `Valgrind` friendly python and use it in your program.

But if you consider something else like `tracemalloc`, then you can easily get some example usage of it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html). The examples are pretty easy to interpret. For  example according to their doc,

```
  import tracemalloc
  tracemalloc.start()

  # ... run your application ...
  snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
  top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
  print("[ Top 10 ]")
  for stat in top_stats[:10]:
  print(stat)
```

This will output something like.

```
 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:716: size=4855 KiB, count=39328, average=126 B
 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:284: size=521 KiB, count=3199, average=167 >
```

You can either parse this to plot memory usage for your investigation or you may
use the reference [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) to get a more concrete idea.

In this case your program could be something like the following:

```
 from tkinter import *
 import tracemalloc
 root = Tk()  # New GUI
 # some code here

 def destructorMethods:
     tracemalloc.start()
     myFunctions.destructorLinkedList()  # Destructor method of my allocated memory in my C file
     # Here is where I would want to run a Valgrind/Memory management check before closing
     snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
     top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
     print("[ Top 10 ]")
     for stat in top_stats[:10]:
         print(stat)
     
     root.destroy()  # close the program

 root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destructorMethods)
```

Another option is, you can use a memory profiler to see memory usage at a variable time. The package is available [here](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/). After the installation of this package, you can probably use the following command in your script to get the memory usage over time in a png file.

```
 mprof run --include-children python your_filename.py
 mprof plot --output timelyplot.png
```

or you may use different functions available on `memory_profiler` package according to your need. Maybe [this](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/hunting-for-memory-leaks-in-python-applications-6824d0518774) tutorial can be an interesting one for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a debug memory allocator, which supports leak detection.

Something like tcmalloc would do. You just LD_PRELOAD it and all your calls to malloc , free etc will debug for leaks .

Answer (score 0):

To [trace python memory leaks](http://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/) have a look at this article and - for more details - to these questions, here on SO:

- [How to use valgrind with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112989/how-to-use-valgrind-with-python)
- [Python memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks)